# Infection through Virtual machine in NAT mode

Tags: malware, virtualization

I have a VM box configured using NAT to my host OS. It seems I can ping to the machines in my LAN. If my VM box got infected somehow my malware while surfing, would the malware be able to infect machines in my LAN? thanks.

Comment: ANY computer that has network access to your network can launch attacks.

Comment: Thanks. the other way is to use "Host Only" mode, right?

Comment: It could infect the _Host_ machine, and the _Host_ would be able to infect the other machines. But this scenario is very unlikely.

Comment: @ThoriumBR if the VM can ping the LAN, why does it have to propagate through infection of the host? Granted, it will likely be on another subnet, but network access is network access.

Comment: @schroeder The infection of the host is needed in the case of a _Host only_ network.

Comment: @thoriumbr that's true, but it wasn't clear in your comment that you switched context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VM box --(virtualnetwork)--> Linux VM with iptables (NAT and restrict only port 80/443, etc) --(nat/bridge)--> Host PC

This will ensure infections in your VM box cannot spread laterally.

And also make sure your user accounts in the VM box are not the same as the ones on your network.